# EOS Token Economy with Contract, Wallet, Account

Tags: smart-contract, tokens, accounts, wallet

i'm trying to making dApp with EOS.

I have some questions.

1. About token.

   - Should i use "eosio.token" contract to make token economy? Or it is just for example? Then should i make new smart contract like in Ethereum?
2. About deploying contract

   - When i deploy my smart contract to nodeos, its command is "cleos set contract account directory -p account@permission".  But if i can not access nodeos in CLI directly, how can i set or deploy contract? Should i request to BP for deploying contract?
3. About wallet and account.

   - If i can not access nodeos in CLI directly, how can i create new account for users in my dApp? Or dApp users don't need eos account? Then how can i manage their token?
   - If i need to create new account for users in my dApp, what is relationship between wallet and account in EOS?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Yes**, the eosio.token contract is a smart contract which allows accounts to create standardardized tokens which Exchanges and other dApps can utilise. Unlike Ethereum where each token will have it's own smart contract, EOS tokens all share the one eosio.token contract.
2. If you're trying to create an account on an EOSIO blockchain you need to be able to connect to it, specify what endpoint you'd like to use with the -u switch in cleos.
3. Not sure what you mean by accessing nodeos in CLI directly. Cleos is used to communicate and set actions to the endpoints. dApp users typically manage their own wallet and approach your dApp from their own accounts.

A **wallet** is simply some software which holds your keypairs (public and private key) things like Exodus, Jaxx etc.

An **account** is registered on the EOSIO blockchain which is controlled by default permission levels owner and active, each with a public key.